How to Efficiently Display and Zoom High-Resolution Building Plans with User-Added Markers in a Flutter App?
I'm building a Flutter app that displays building plans as images, similar to Google Maps functionality. Users can pan and zoom on the image and add custom markers to it. I need help designing an efficient way to handle high-resolution images without overwhelming memory usage, as well as managing different image quality levels depending on the zoom level. Here are the main requirements:

Display High-Resolution Images with Zoom and Pan: The building plan should be viewable at a high resolution, allowing users to zoom in for fine details. I currently consider using InteractiveViewer for zooming and panning but am concerned about potential memory issues if I load the full-resolution image directly.
Dynamic Image Quality Based on Zoom Level: To optimize performance, I’d like to load different image qualities based on the zoom level (e.g., low, medium, high, and original quality). For example, at a low zoom level, the app should display a low-quality image, and as the user zooms in, it would switch to a higher-quality version. The challenge here is to handle this image swapping efficiently to avoid loading multiple large images into memory simultaneously.
Displaying User-Added Markers on the Image: Users should be able to place markers on the image (like pins or points of interest), which should remain positioned correctly across zoom and pan interactions.

Questions:

What is the best way to load and display a high-resolution image for zooming and panning in Flutter? Is InteractiveViewer the right approach, or are there other widgets or packages better suited for this?
How can I manage multiple image quality levels based on zoom to save memory? Are there strategies in Flutter to handle conditional loading or swapping of image assets depending on zoom level without loading them all into memory at once?
Any tips on implementing marker overlay functionality on the image that remains responsive to panning and zooming?
Any guidance, code samples, or package recommendations to achieve these goals efficiently would be greatly appreciated!


first of all you need tiled images, fir example for density 1x you could have one tile, for density 2x you should have 2^2 tiles (4) and for density 3x you should have 3^2 tiles (9) - otherwise there is no point in using different quality levels since for max density you would need to load one huge hi-res image

of course the number of tiles for each level can be adjusted: for example if you have 4 tiles for density 2x (grid 2x2) and you pan your content exactly to the center all of them will be used (top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right), so you could create more "dense" grid for example 4x4 (and not 2x2)
